# How can I change text feeded to spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

Let's say I have sentence

```
Hello my name is John name
 What is your name
```

and I would like to keep only word `name` and change all rest to `-` but keep format of input so final result would look like:

```
- - name - - name
 - - - name
```

I tried using

```
new_words = [token.text if token.text=="Name" else "-" for token in doc]
Doc(doc.vocab, words=new_words)
```

but when I printed out my doc it was still same doc nothing changed.

Comment: Do you mean you want to preserve whitespace between the words? Do you only have alphanumeric words in your sentences? Or can the be punctuation, too? Try the regex approach, `re.sub(r'\b(?!name\b)\w+', "-", text, flags=re.I)`

Comment: I mean not even whitespaces that it could look like paragraphs/text even after my visualization

Comment: Ok, so the above does not work? Try `re.sub(r'\S+', lambda x: x.group() if x.group().lower() == 'name' else '-', text)`

Comment: Actually, the fastest seems to be `re.sub(r'(?i)(?<!\S)(?!name(?!\S))\S+', "-", text)`, does it help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a simple missing variable assignment in the example above:

```py
new_words = [token.text if token.text=="Name" else "-" for token in doc]
doc = Doc(doc.vocab, words=new_words)
```

If you want to preserve whitespace, add:

```py
new_words = [token.text if token.text=="Name" else "-" for token in doc]
spaces = [bool(token.whitespace_) for token in doc]
doc = Doc(doc.vocab, words=new_words, spaces=spaces)
```

Comment: Well I get semi result which I want. But atleast I get something in right direction thank you. I would like not only to keep whitespaces but keep format of text like paragraphs etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace any chunk of non-whitespace chars that is not equal to `name` in a case insensitive way with a hyphen:

```py
import re
text = """Hello my name is John name
 What is your name"""
print( re.sub(r'(?i)(?<!\S)(?!name(?!\S))\S+', "-", text) )
# => - - name - - name
#     - - - name
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/c5gddZ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N0nkAf/2).

*Pattern details*

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive modifier
- `(?<!\S)` - the current location in string should be the start of string or
  immediately preceded with a whitespace
- `(?!name(?!\S))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `name` followed with whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.